# Need help figuring out why Im getting a File Sharing Failure STATUS=61 message at runtime

Tags: linux, file-io, runtime-error, cobol, gnucobol

For a homework assignment we are practicing multilevel control breaks in file processing. We grab data from an input file, process each group (in this case: a property management routine that calculates total rent for the month from offices, buildings, and managing agents), and spit the data out in a nice neat report file. I've written and provided a link to what I've got so far. It's rough in that I haven't bothered with output formatting yet, just wanted to make sure I could get it running first. It compiles with zero errors or warnings under the "-free" switch. However when I go to run the program I'm greeted with the following message:

```
libcob: File sharing conflict (STATUS = 61) File : 'income-report.txt'
WARNING - Implicit CLOSE of propmanager-in-file ("prop-records.txt")
```

After some searching I learn that the "STATUS = 61" code for file I/O is usually thrown when an OPEN is being performed on a physical file that is already opened with another file connector. At the time I had the income-report.txt open in another vi window. I closed it, recompiled, ran it, and got the same message. I'm stumped.

income-report.txt and prop-record.txt are in the same directory as the program. Neither files were open anywhere on my machine the last time I compiled and I still received the above message.

Link to code: http://pastebin.com/WrPuTUW9

Answer (score 3):

We'll be able to help you more in the discussion forums on the OpenCOBOL project at SourceForge.  There we can discuss in a more free form, and not be restricted to the Question and Answer format preferred here.  Not complaining about that, but I think you might benefit from a more open forum, as there may be some misunderstandings we can help with.

I have a feeling you are mistaking compile time and run time.  It won't matter what data files you have open when you **compile** your program.  The file sharing status code is a **run-time** error.  I'm guessing you have your data files open when you execute the program.

Head to SourceForge and we'll help more if we can.